# Paste Event on html div without content editable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I need to bind the paste event on div, so that i can grab the image from clipboard and assign it to a angular scope variable. This works fine in chrome but it doesn't work on IE 11 without adding `contenteditable=true` attribute. The problem with content editable is it breaks existing drag and drop featue of div.

I was looking similar to snag.gy where we can paste without contenteditable.

Any guidance please

[update]
Js Fiddle for test https://jsfiddle.net/sfL6ympx/
- you can remove contenteditable=true and check

Comment: how do you get the div focused so it can accept events? Maybe the problem in IE is that div is not focused?

Comment: div has min-height, so I can click on div and can focus. It works on chrome

Comment: _works on chrome_ never helped me to solve the IE issues. The information you give here is far not enough. You should post the sample on jsfiddle / whatsoever.

Comment: "without adding `contentEditable=true` it doesn't work anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, with a little bit of reverse engineering we can see that snag.gy *does* use `contenteditable=true`, with some css to hide it and some javascript to make sure it gets the focus before the paste event.

Here's how to do it:

- **Demo**: https://jsfiddle.net/raine/zyf40Lnc/40/show
- **Fiddle**: https://jsfiddle.net/raine/zyf40Lnc/40/

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<style type="text/css">
/* invisible paste capture element */
#paste-capture-parent {
  z-index: -500;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
}
#paste-capture-area {
  -webkit-user-select: auto !important
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
  
<div id="paste-capture-parent">
  <div id="paste-capture-area" contenteditable="true"></div>
</div>
<pre id="output"></pre>

<script type="text/javascript">

// get elements
const captureArea = document.getElementById('paste-capture-area')
const output = document.getElementById('output')

// focus the capture area when a key is pressed
document.addEventListener('keydown', () => captureArea.focus())

// detect paste on capture area
captureArea.addEventListener('paste', e => {
  const text = e.clipboardData.getData('text/plain')
  output.innerHTML += `You pasted: "${text}"\n`
})

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you're trying to do. But, snag.gy does it without `contenteditable=true` because their pasting event is not dependent on a particular element in their DOM. So, it's a `window.onkeyDown` event.

You can combine them both for your need. Once, the div is clicked, set the focus on it. And when there is a `keyDown` event on that div, check:

`if( (event.keyCode == 86 || event.which == 86) && event.ctrlKey )`

'86' is the keyCode for V. Then, execute your code within that block!

Comment: You can make the div to accept focus with `tabindex=1`.

Comment: Thanks, I will try and get back